# Integral quaternary forms and theta functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, theta-series

The following question arises when I attempt to understand the modular parameterization of the elliptic curve $$E:y^2-y=x^3-x$$

In [Mazur-Swinnerton-Dyer](https://eudml.org/doc/142281) and [Zagier](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BFb0084592/fulltext.pdf)'s construction, a theta function associated with a positive definite quadratic form is induced:

$$\theta(q)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^4}q^{\frac{1}{2}x^{T}Ax}$$

where $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 4 & 1 &2\\
1 & 1 & 10 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 20
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$A$ is a positive definite matrix of determinant $37^2$, and we have $37A^{-1}=K^TAK$ where $K$ is an integral matrix of determinant $\pm 1$.

**Question:** Suppose $A$ is a positive definite $4\times 4$ matrix with integral entries. All diagonal entries are even numbers. The determinant of $A$ is a square number $N^2$. Is it true that for every $N=p$ ($p>2$ is a prime number), there is *at least one* $A$ that $NA^{-1}=K^TAK$, where $K$ is an integral matrix of determinant $\pm 1$?

Comment: In your question, do you want to assume $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix? It's a little unclear which parameters depend on which here.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: Yes, $A$ should be a $4\times 4$ matrix. The title of the question is about "quaternary forms", but I think I should emphasis that $A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: since this question is about explicit modular paramtetrization, let me put a link to a related question I asked: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96621/shimura-taniyama-weil-vs-grothendiecks-dessins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is true, using the following construction.
Let $B$ be the quaternion algebra of discriminant $p$ and let $O$ be a maximal order with an element $x$ satisfying $x^2 = -p$. The reduced norm is a quadratic form on $O$, with positive definite Gram matrix $A$ of determinant $p^2$. The matrix $A^{-1}$ then represents the reduced norm on the dual lattice $O^{\sharp}$. Recall that $\text{nrd}(\text{diff}(O)) = \text{discrd}(O) = p$ and since $O$ is maximal, $\text{diff}(O)$ is invertible and $O = \text{diff}(O) O^{\sharp}$ (see e.g.
*Voight, John*, [**Quaternion algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-56694-4),  [ZBL07261776](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07261776). Section 16.8), hence
$$
p O^{\sharp} \subseteq \text{diff}(O) O^{\sharp} = O
$$
which implies that $p \cdot (O^{\sharp} / O) = 0$ (therefore $O^{\sharp} / O$ is an abelian group of exponent $p$ and size $p^2$, so isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z})^2$). Next, we note that the matrix $A^{-1}$ is also the change of basis matrix between the chosen basis of $O$ and its dual, therefore $pA^{-1}$ is integral.

This is not enough, but so far we have not used the element $x$. The matrix $pA^{-1}$ is the matrix representing the norm form on the ideal $xO^{\sharp}$, since $x^2 = -p$. But $nrd(xO^{\sharp})=p$ is a maximal order with an element $x$ such that $x^2 = -p$. By a theorem of Ibukiyama (see reference below), it is isomorphic (hence isometric as lattices) to $O$.

This could also be seen directly (referring to some of the answers above - it is possible to do it using a finite number of cases) by explicitly writing down the maximal orders. I will list below explicit constructions, which are based on
*Ibukiyama, Tomoyoshi*, [**On maximal orders of division quaternion algebras over the rational number field with certain optimal embeddings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S002776300002016X), Nagoya Math. J. 88, 181-195 (1982). [ZBL0473.12012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0473.12012). -

If $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, then $B = (-p,-1)$, and $O = \mathbb{Z}<(1+i)/2,j>$. In this case, we have
$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & \frac{p+1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{p+1}{2}
\end{array} \right)
,
pA^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
\frac{p+1}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{p+1}{2} & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2
\end{array} \right),
K = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right)
$$

If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then choosing $q \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ such that
$\left( \frac{q}{p} \right) = -1$, we can find $c$ such that
$c^2 \equiv -p \bmod q$, and then $B = (-p,-q)$ and
$$
O = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \frac{1+j}{2} \oplus
\mathbb{Z} \frac{i(1+j)}{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \frac{(c+i)j}{q}
$$
In this case, we compute that
$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & \frac{q+1}{2} & 0 & c \\
0 & 0 & \frac{p(q+1)}{2} & p \\
0 & c & p & \frac{2(p+c^2)}{q}
\end{array} \right)
,
pA^{-1} = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
\frac{(q+1)(c^2+p)}{2q} & -c-\frac{c^2+p}{q} & -c & \frac{c(q+1)}{2} \\ 
-c-\frac{c^2+p}{q} & 2(c^2 + \frac{c^2+p}{q}) & 2c & -c(q+1) \\
-c & 2c & 2 & -q \\
\frac{c(q+1)}{2} & -c(q+1) & -q & \frac{q(q+1)}{2}
\end{array} \right)
$$

and if $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4 \}$ is the above basis for $O$, then we see that $ \{e_2 e_4, ce_1 - e_4, e_1, j e_2 \} $ is a basis for the resulting module, which written in terms of the original basis yields the matrix
$$
K = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & c & 1 & -\frac{q+1}{2} \\
-c & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{q+1}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
 \right).
$$

Referring to Will Jagy's wondering in the first answer, the reason that this does not work for most lattices is that they do not correspond to a maximal order (as in the answer by few_reps, the quotient of the lattices is actually cyclic) and there are only one or two (depending on $p \bmod 4$ isomorphism classes of maximal orders which contain a root of $-p$. For example, for $p = 37$, there are only two isomorphism classes of maximal orders in the quaternion algebra, and only one of them contains a root of $-p$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_p$ be the set of isometry classes of 4-dimensional positive definite lattices  satisfying the property $L^\sharp/L\simeq (\mathbf Z/p)^2$. The set $X_n$ is stable under the involution $\tau : L\mapsto pL^\sharp$.

The question seems to ask whether or not $X_p^\tau$ contains an even lattice. Will Jagy has given evidences for a positive answer. Nevertheless, one might ask whether the same holds when one restricts the question to a given genus (genera are also stable under $\tau$), even or odd.

**Further edit** Feb. 22 : Interestingly, the case of odd lattices seems to allow the opposite behaviour:

```
p= 7  A=
            [ 7  0  0  0]
            [ 0  3  1 -1]
            [ 0  1  2 -1]
            [ 0 -1 -1  2]
fix= 0    move= 2   proportion= 0.000

p= 23  A=
            [23  0  0  0]
            [ 0  5 -1  0]
            [ 0 -1  3 -1]
            [ 0  0 -1  2]
fix= 0    move= 4   proportion= 0.000

p= 31  A=
            [31  0  0  0]
            [ 0  6 -1 -1]
            [ 0 -1  3  0]
            [ 0 -1  0  2]
fix= 0    move= 8   proportion= 0.000

p= 47  A=
            [47  0  0  0]
            [ 0  6 -2  1]
            [ 0 -2  5  0]
            [ 0  1  0  2]
fix= 0    move= 12   proportion= 0.000

p= 71  A=
            [71  0  0  0]
            [ 0  7  1  1]
            [ 0  1  6  1]
            [ 0  1  1  2]
fix= 0    move= 20   proportion= 0.000

p= 79  A=
            [79  0  0  0]
            [ 0  6  0  1]
            [ 0  0  5 -1]
            [ 0  1 -1  3]
fix= 0    move= 26   proportion= 0.000

p= 103  A=
            [103   0   0   0]
            [  0  18  -1  -1]
            [  0  -1   3   0]
            [  0  -1   0   2]
fix= 0    move= 50   proportion= 0.000

p= 127  A=
            [127   0   0   0]
            [  0  10  -2   1]
            [  0  -2   5  -1]
            [  0   1  -1   3]
fix= 0    move= 62   proportion= 0.000

p= 151  A=
            [151   0   0   0]
            [  0  11  -1   0]
            [  0  -1   5   1]
            [  0   0   1   3]
fix= 0    move= 78   proportion= 0.000

p= 167  A=
            [167   0   0   0]
            [  0  18  -2  -1]
            [  0  -2   5   0]
            [  0  -1   0   2]
fix= 0    move= 92   proportion= 0.000

p= 191  A=
            [191   0   0   0]
            [  0  14   0   1]
            [  0   0   5  -1]
            [  0   1  -1   3]
fix= 0    move= 114   proportion= 0.000

p= 199  A=
            [199   0   0   0]
            [  0   7   1   1]
            [  0   1   6   0]
            [  0   1   0   5]
fix= 0    move= 134   proportion= 0.000

p= 223  A=
            [223   0   0   0]
            [  0  11   3  -3]
            [  0   3   6  -2]
            [  0  -3  -2   5]
fix= 0    move= 182   proportion= 0.000

p= 239  A=
            [239   0   0   0]
            [  0  19   2   0]
            [  0   2   7  -1]
            [  0   0  -1   2]
fix= 0    move= 172   proportion= 0.000
```

**Edit** Feb. 21 : Here are some heuristics (in each case, there is a quadratic space $V$ on which some lattices $L$ with $q(L)\subset \mathbf Z$ will furnish Gram matrices $A$ such as required in the OP (recall that in that case, the Gram matrix is associated to the bilinear form $x.y=q(x+y)-q(x)-q(y)$, in particular it has even diagonal entries).

Let $p$ be a prime, congruent to $3$ mod $4$. Then there is such a genus on the $\mathbf Q$-quadratic space $[1,1,p,p]$. Here is the number of fixed (resp exchanged) lattices:

```
p=  3  fix= 1    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  7  fix= 1    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  11  fix= 3    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  19  fix= 3    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  23  fix= 6    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  31  fix= 6    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  43  fix= 5    move= 2   proportion= 0.714
p=  47  fix= 15    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  59  fix= 21    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  67  fix= 7    move= 6   proportion= 0.538
p=  71  fix= 28    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  79  fix= 20    move= 2   proportion= 0.909
p=  83  fix= 27    move= 2   proportion= 0.931
p=  103  fix= 25    move= 6   proportion= 0.807
p=  107  fix= 33    move= 6   proportion= 0.846
p=  127  fix= 30    move= 12   proportion= 0.714
p=  131  fix= 65    move= 2   proportion= 0.970
p=  139  fix= 39    move= 12   proportion= 0.765
p=  151  fix= 49    move= 12   proportion= 0.804
p=  163  fix= 15    move= 42   proportion= 0.263
p=  167  fix= 88    move= 6   proportion= 0.937
p=  179  fix= 85    move= 12   proportion= 0.876
p=  191  fix= 117    move= 6   proportion= 0.951
p=  199  fix= 81    move= 20   proportion= 0.802
p=  211  fix= 57    move= 42   proportion= 0.576
p=  223  fix= 70    move= 42   proportion= 0.625
p=  227  fix= 105    move= 30   proportion= 0.777
p=  239  fix= 165    move= 12   proportion= 0.933
p=  251  fix= 161    move= 20   proportion= 0.890
p=  263  fix= 156    move= 30   proportion= 0.839
p=  271  fix= 132    move= 42   proportion= 0.759
p=  283  fix= 75    move= 90   proportion= 0.455
p=  307  fix= 81    move= 110   proportion= 0.424
p=  311  fix= 266    move= 20   proportion= 0.930
p=  331  fix= 87    move= 132   proportion= 0.397
p=  347  fix= 155    move= 110   proportion= 0.585
p=  359  fix= 304    move= 42   proportion= 0.879
p=  367  fix= 144    move= 132   proportion= 0.521
p=  379  fix= 99    move= 182   proportion= 0.353
p=  383  fix= 289    move= 72   proportion= 0.801
p=  419  fix= 333    move= 90   proportion= 0.787
p=  431  fix= 399    move= 72   proportion= 0.847
p=  439  fix= 285    move= 132   proportion= 0.684
p=  443  fix= 195    move= 210   proportion= 0.481
p=  463  fix= 140    move= 272   proportion= 0.340
p=  467  fix= 287    move= 182   proportion= 0.612
p=  479  fix= 525    move= 72   proportion= 0.880
p=  487  fix= 147    move= 306   proportion= 0.325
p=  491  fix= 387    move= 156   proportion= 0.713
p=  499  fix= 129    move= 342   proportion= 0.274
```

Similarly, in the following cases, there exist such a genus on $A_2\perp p.A_2$:

```
p=  5  fix= 1    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  11  fix= 3    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  17  fix= 3    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  23  fix= 6    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  29  fix= 6    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  41  fix= 10    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  47  fix= 15    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  53  fix= 9    move= 2   proportion= 0.818
p=  59  fix= 21    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  71  fix= 28    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  83  fix= 27    move= 2   proportion= 0.931
p=  89  fix= 27    move= 2   proportion= 0.931
p=  101  fix= 35    move= 2   proportion= 0.946
p=  107  fix= 33    move= 6   proportion= 0.846
p=  113  fix= 22    move= 12   proportion= 0.647
p=  131  fix= 65    move= 2   proportion= 0.970
p=  137  fix= 26    move= 20   proportion= 0.565
p=  149  fix= 49    move= 12   proportion= 0.804
p=  167  fix= 88    move= 6   proportion= 0.937
p=  173  fix= 56    move= 20   proportion= 0.737
p=  179  fix= 85    move= 12   proportion= 0.876
p=  191  fix= 117    move= 6   proportion= 0.951
p=  197  fix= 45    move= 42   proportion= 0.518
p=  227  fix= 105    move= 30   proportion= 0.777
p=  233  fix= 63    move= 56   proportion= 0.529
p=  239  fix= 165    move= 12   proportion= 0.933
p=  251  fix= 161    move= 20   proportion= 0.890
p=  257  fix= 92    move= 56   proportion= 0.622
p=  263  fix= 156    move= 30   proportion= 0.839
p=  269  fix= 132    move= 42   proportion= 0.759
p=  281  fix= 125    move= 56   proportion= 0.690
p=  293  fix= 117    move= 72   proportion= 0.619
```

Here is a final example : on the $\mathbf Q$-quadratic space $<1,2>\perp p.<1,2>$ (here, the example in the OP, developped in my first answer, appears):

```
p=  5  fix= 1    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  7  fix= 1    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  13  fix= 1    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  23  fix= 6    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  29  fix= 6    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  31  fix= 6    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  37  fix= 2    move= 2   proportion= 0.500
p=  47  fix= 15    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  53  fix= 9    move= 2   proportion= 0.818
p=  61  fix= 9    move= 2   proportion= 0.818
p=  71  fix= 28    move= 0   proportion= 1.00
p=  79  fix= 20    move= 2   proportion= 0.909
p=  101  fix= 35    move= 2   proportion= 0.946
p=  103  fix= 25    move= 6   proportion= 0.807
p=  109  fix= 15    move= 12   proportion= 0.556
p=  127  fix= 30    move= 12   proportion= 0.714
p=  149  fix= 49    move= 12   proportion= 0.804
p=  151  fix= 49    move= 12   proportion= 0.804
p=  157  fix= 21    move= 30   proportion= 0.412
p=  167  fix= 88    move= 6   proportion= 0.937
p=  173  fix= 56    move= 20   proportion= 0.737
p=  181  fix= 40    move= 30   proportion= 0.571
p=  191  fix= 117    move= 6   proportion= 0.951
p=  197  fix= 45    move= 42   proportion= 0.518
p=  199  fix= 81    move= 20   proportion= 0.802
p=  223  fix= 70    move= 42   proportion= 0.625
p=  229  fix= 50    move= 56   proportion= 0.472
p=  239  fix= 165    move= 12   proportion= 0.933
p=  263  fix= 156    move= 30   proportion= 0.839
p=  269  fix= 132    move= 42   proportion= 0.759
p=  271  fix= 132    move= 42   proportion= 0.759
p=  277  fix= 36    move= 110   proportion= 0.247
p=  293  fix= 117    move= 72   proportion= 0.619
p=  311  fix= 266    move= 20   proportion= 0.930
p=  317  fix= 70    move= 132   proportion= 0.347
p=  349  fix= 105    move= 132   proportion= 0.443
p=  359  fix= 304    move= 42   proportion= 0.879
p=  367  fix= 144    move= 132   proportion= 0.521
p=  373  fix= 80    move= 182   proportion= 0.305
p=  383  fix= 289    move= 72   proportion= 0.801
p=  389  fix= 187    move= 132   proportion= 0.586
p=  397  fix= 51    move= 240   proportion= 0.175
p=  421  fix= 90    move= 240   proportion= 0.273
p=  431  fix= 399    move= 72   proportion= 0.847
p=  439  fix= 285    move= 132   proportion= 0.684
p=  461  fix= 300    move= 156   proportion= 0.658
p=  463  fix= 140    move= 272   proportion= 0.340
p=  479  fix= 525    move= 72   proportion= 0.880
p=  487  fix= 147    move= 306   proportion= 0.325
```

Studying these repartitions seems to be quite interesting.

**Original post :**

The answer is no : if you run the following Magma code :

```
M:=Matrix(Integers(),4,4,[1,0,1,1,0,2,1,2,0,0,5,1,0,0,0,10]);
M:=M+Transpose(M);
L:=LatticeWithGram(M);
H:=GenusRepresentatives(L);
for h in H do
    print "h= lattice with Gram", GramMatrix(h);
    hd:=DualBasisLattice(h);
    MD:=37*LLLGram(GramMatrix(hd));
    print "rescaled dual = lattice with Gram", MD;    
    a,b:=IsIsometric(h,LatticeWithGram(MD));
    print "are isometric : ", a;
    print " ";
end for;
```

on the [online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), you obtain the following result :

```
h= lattice with Gram
[ 2  0  1  1]
[ 0  4  1  2]
[ 1  1 10  1]
[ 1  2  1 20]
rescaled dual = lattice with Gram
[ 2  0 -1 -1]
[ 0  4 -1 -2]
[-1 -1 10  1]
[-1 -2  1 20]
are isometric : true

h= lattice with Gram
[ 4 -1  2  1]
[-1  4 -1  0]
[ 2 -1  6 -2]
[ 1  0 -2 20]
rescaled dual = lattice with Gram
[ 2  1 -1  0]
[ 1  8 -4  1]
[-1 -4 12  2]
[ 0  1  2 10]
are isometric : false

h= lattice with Gram
[ 4  1  1  1]
[ 1  6  3  1]
[ 1  3  8 -1]
[ 1  1 -1 10]
rescaled dual = lattice with Gram
[ 4  1 -1 -1]
[ 1  6 -3 -1]
[-1 -3  8 -1]
[-1 -1 -1 10]
are isometric : true

h= lattice with Gram
[ 2  1  0 -1]
[ 1  8 -1 -4]
[ 0 -1 10 -2]
[-1 -4 -2 12]
rescaled dual = lattice with Gram
[ 4  1  1  0]
[ 1  4  2  1]
[ 1  2  6 -2]
[ 0  1 -2 20]
are isometric : false
```

Comment: Eh..... Why do you think the answer is "no" for determinant $37^2$? At least two matrices in your calculation support my idea.

Comment: hmm sorry, I misunderstood the question ... I'm gonna modify the algorithm to search for a counter-example to your very question ...

Comment: @zy_, you did not word this well. If all you want is one $A$ of the discriminant, whenever $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ there will always be one, because there is a quaternary made from the sum of two identical binaries.

Comment: @zy_ the identical binaries can be the principal form $x^2 + xy + \left( \frac{p+1}{4} \right) y^2$

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you so much. I checked all primes $p<41$, and found no counterexamples.

Comment: @zy_ ok, so I guess I should delete this answer ...

Comment: @WillJagy Would you make your comment in an answer ?

Comment: few_reps, give me a few minutes, I may have something. Also i think you answered this in good faith and should leave this here, it is good information.

Comment: @WillJagy All right !

Comment: few, I think that performing this operation twice should always return you to the original form, with discriminant $p^2.$ If so, we are guaranteed a fixed form (as the OP wants) when the class number is odd, to add to the two trivial infinite families in my answer.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, it is an involution since $(L^\sharp)^\sharp=L$ and $(pL)^\sharp=\frac 1p L^\sharp$.

Comment: @WillJagy But the class number is often even (I'm performing heuristics right now) ...

Comment: @few_reps: Thanks for your calculation! In the $d=37^2$ case, the involution fixes the first and the third lattice, while it swaps the second and the fourth one.

Answer (score 2):

dunno. few_reps found that all the other forms of discriminant $37^2$ fail. Go figure. Here are all the examples from [Nipp's extended tables](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/nipp.html#form) at [Nebe's website](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/). To get the matrix, double f11, f22, f33, f44, but keep the others as they are, and make the matrix symmetric.

```
  lower case g is just a genus ID number. G is the size of the automorphism group.
  d    g  f11 f22 f33 f44 f12 f13 f23 f14 f24 f34  H  level = N   G    m1   m2
   9   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1 -1-1         3  288    1  288
  25   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   0   1   1   2 -1-1         5   72    1   72
  49   1   1   1   2   2   0   1   0   0   1   0 -1-1         7   32    1   32
 121   1   1   1   3   3   0   1   0   0   1   0 -1-1        11   32   25  288
 121   1   1   1   4   4   1   1   0   1   1   4 -1-1        11   72   25  288
 121   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   0   1   1   2 -1-1        11   24   25  288
 169   1   1   2   2   4   1   0   1   1   1   2 -1-1        13    8    1    8
 289   1   1   1   6   6   1   1   0   1   1   6 -1-1        17   72    2    9
 289   1   1   2   3   5   1   0   2   0   1   3 -1-1        17    8    2    9
 289   1   2   2   3   3   2   1   0   1   1   3 -1-1        17   12    2    9
 361   1   1   1   5   5   0   1   0   0   1   0 -1-1        19   32    9   32
 361   1   1   2   3   6   1   1   0   1   2   3 -1-1        19    8    9   32
 361   1   2   2   3   3   0   2   1   1   2   1 -1-1        19    8    9   32
 529   1   1   1   6   6   0   1   0   0   1   0 -1-1        23   32  121  288
 529   1   1   1   8   8   1   1   0   1   1   8 -1-1        23   72  121  288
 529   1   1   2   3   6   0   0   1   1   0   0 -1-1        23    8  121  288
 529   1   2   2   3   3   0   1   0   0   1   0 -1-1        23    8  121  288
 529   1   2   2   4   4   2   1   0   1   1   4 -1-1        23   12  121  288
 529   1   3   3   3   3   3   2   0   2   2   3 -1-1        23   24  121  288
 841   1   1   1  10  10   1   1   0   1   1  10 -1-1        29   72   49   72
 841   1   1   2   4   8   0   1   1   1   2   1 -1-1        29    8   49   72
 841   1   1   3   3   8   1   0   2   0   1   3 -1-1        29    8   49   72
 841   1   2   2   4   4   1   1   0   0  -1   2 -1-1        29    4   49   72
 841   1   2   2   5   5   2   1   0   1   1   5 -1-1        29   12   49   72
 841   1   3   3   4   4   3   2  -1   2   3   3 -1-1        29   12   49   72
 961   1   1   1   8   8   0   1   0   0   1   0 -1-1        31   32   25   32
 961   1   1   2   4   8   0   0   1   1   0   0 -1-1        31    8   25   32
 961   1   1   2   5   9   1   0   2   0   1   5 -1-1        31    8   25   32
 961   1   2   2   4   4   0   1   0   0   1   0 -1-1        31    8   25   32
 961   1   2   3   4   5   2   0   3   1   2   4 -1-1        31    4   25   32
 961   1   3   3   3   3   2   1   0   0   1  -2 -1-1        31    8   25   32
1369   1   1   2   5  10   0   1   1   1   2   1 -1-1        37    8    9    8
1369   1   1   4   5   6   1   0   1   0   4   3 -1-1        37    4    9    8
1369   1   2   2   3  10   1   2   0   1   0   3 -1-1        37    4    9    8
1369   1   2   3   4   5   1   0   3   1   1   2 -1-1        37    2    9    8
1681   1   1   1  14  14   1   1   0   1   1  14 -1-1        41   72   25   18
1681   1   1   2   6  12   1   0   1   1   1   6 -1-1        41    8   25   18
1681   1   1   3   4  11   0   1   2   0   3   1 -1-1        41    8   25   18
1681   1   1   3   4  12   1   1   0   1   3   4 -1-1        41    8   25   18
1681   1   2   2   6   6   1   2   0   1   2   3 -1-1        41    4   25   18
1681   1   2   2   7   7   2   1   0   1   1   7 -1-1        41   12   25   18
1681   1   2   3   4   6   0   2   1   1   3   1 -1-1        41    4   25   18
1681   1   3   3   4   4   1   2  -1   1  -2   2 -1-1        41    4   25   18
1681   1   3   3   5   5   3   2   0   2   2   5 -1-1        41   12   25   18
1681   1   4   4   4   4   4   2  -1   3   2   4 -1-1        41   12   25   18
  d    g  f11 f22 f33 f44 f12 f13 f23 f14 f24 f34  H  level = N   G    m1   m2
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the OP will be satisfied with just one form for each of these square discriminants that maps to itself. I should already say that this thing reminds me of Watson transformations. However, few_reps has shown that some of the forms of the genus interchange. It seems this mapping permutes the genus, and one might need to search for a very long time to find a case when this permutation is a derangement.

I  have two (infinite sets of) examples that suggest a derangement is going to be hard to find.  If prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ make a quaternary form out of two copies of the binary $x^2 + xy + \left( \frac{q+1}{4} \right) y^2.$ This works, so half the primes are finished.

Next, if $p = 6k-1,$ take matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 4k & 2k \\
1 & 1 & 2k & 4k
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with determinant $p^2.$
The inverse times $p$ is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
4k & -2k & -1 & 0 \\
-2k & 4k & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
I will need to check for the explicit change of variables matrix, but it looks good.

Got it, in

$$
K =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Following Zagier, I can cover $p=8k-3$ with

$$A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 4 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 2k & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 0 & 4k
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @zy_ in that case, i would expect that enough effort would produce recipes for $5k  + 2,3$ more work $7k+3,5,6.$ This is not the sort of problem where a finite number of such cases are going to finish the job. I did not see that Zagier really cared about all positive quaternaries of a given discriminant, just some compatible with the modular forms material.